# React Native Webview is not working on android after generating apk or aab

Tags: android, react-native, webview

react-native-webview is working good on development. But, after generating apk or aab file, it's not working and just displaying a white screen as below. Please help to fix it.

[image]

**Here's my codes**

import {View} from 'react-native';
import React, {useState} from 'react';

import {WebView} from 'react-native-webview';

import Loader from '../../components/Loader/Loader';

import styles from './styles';

const Playnow = () => {
const [load, setLoad] = useState(false);

return (
<>
{load && }

```
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <WebView
      onLoadStart={() => {
        setLoad(!load);
      }}
      onLoadEnd={() => {
        setLoad(!load);
      }}
      style={styles.web}
      source={{uri: 'my-uri'}}
      allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs={true}
      allowFileAccessFromFileURLs={true}
      allowingReadAccessToURL={`my-uri`}
      javaScriptEnabled={true}
      domStorageEnabled={true}
      startInLoadingState={true}
    />
  </View>
</>
```

);
};

export default Playnow;

**Here's my styling codes**

import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
flex: 1,
backgroundColor: '#262626',
},
web: {
flex: 1,
backgroundColor: '#262626',
},
});

export default styles;

Answer (score 0):

To perform network operations in your application, your manifest must include the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Yeah I already added.